# Omitting inline ASM code in C source code

Tags: c, visual-c++, assembly, inline-assembly

While using MS VC98, is there a way to omit compiling inline ASM code in a C source ?

Comment: Could you clarify? You already have asm code and you don't want to compile it?

Comment: You can comment out any portion of the code, but will it serve the purpose that you want?

Comment: My intent was to specifically remove the asm code from compilation from existing source code. wrapping each block under flags is practically not feasible in my case.

Answer (score 3):

There's no magic switch built into the compiler to do this. You'll have to do it with the pre-processor and I can't see any alternative to wrapping all such blocks in `#ifdef`.

Comment: Thank you for you reply but my intent was to specifically remove the asm code from compilation from existing source code. wrapping each block under flags is practically not feasible in my case.

Comment: The first sentence in my answer is meant to convey the fact that what you specifically want to do is not feasible.